# Code First Data Annotations for Backpointer Properties

Tags: ef-code-first, data-annotations, code-first

I'm using Code First.  I've got a Topic class and a Vote Class.  Topics have votes.

```
public class Topic
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
}
```

Vote class points back to Topic so I can get the topic of a given Vote in code.

```
public class Vote
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsUp { get; set; }
    public DateTime WhenVoted { get; set; }
    public Topic Topic { get; set; }
}
```

When I query like `var topics = context.Topics.Include("Votes");`, I get a stack overflow, but if I remove the reference to Topic from Vote, it loads fine.  I believe there's a data annotation I can add to indicate that these represent the same relationship.  Can someone point me in the right direction if that's the case?

The call stack has this over and over again which just seems to indicate that the serializer is trying to recursively render the recursive relationship.  So maybe telling the Vote object not to serialize the Topic property is the right answer here, but if there is a data annotation answer, I'd like to know what it is.

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)  Unknown
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract dataContract, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    Unknown
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract dataContract, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)   Unknown
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) Unknown
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    Unknown
```

Comment: the annotations http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583   ,  include the stacktrace so others can help

Comment: How does database first handle this kind of relationship when auto-generating the .cs?

Answer (score 0):

This was a badly worded question in that I assumed falsely that my problem could be fixed with data annotations.  The answer to my actual question is to use the InverseProperty data annotation to create back pointer references (A has a collection of B, B has a parent property of A).  This however didn't solve the problem since I was serializing a full object model that had the circular references in the code sample.  To get around that, I went down the path of setting up my model to enforce proper serialization with the DataContract, DataMember, and ReferenceType attributes to end the circular reference, and while this worked, the fact that I had to do it was a clear indication I was serializing something not meant for serialization.  In instead created a model specifically for serialization, mapped my domain to that, and serialized that instead with the default json/xml serializer and everything worked out just hunky dory.